# Connect obdsim to Torque(android app) mac

Tags: android, macos

I have the Torque android app and I have downloaded the OBD simulator obdgpslogger-0.16.tar.gz.Run the following commands
tar -zxvf obdgpslogger-0.16.tar.gz
cd obdgpslogger-0.16
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. 
make obdsim
cd ../bin/
./obdsim -b -g gui_fltk
Now simulator has been started ,next step is 
to connect the simulator with torque app.I have bluetooth paired the mac with the android device.
Now in windows we need to run the following command 
Run obdsim.exe -w COM10 and it starts working What to do in mac,in mac this command saying invalid option -w